# Any column limits in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, limit

I have created some tables with more than 800 columns. But I see only the values of approximately 500 columns. Is there any limit or what other causes are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://community.hortonworks.com/answers/6384/view.html):

> I am not aware of any "hard" limitation in hive in regards to column count, there are some on column size though. This being said a restriction on column count would also probably depend on the file format, ORC having indexes and predicate pushdown does not behave as a Text file would. ORC has configurations for number of rows that are grouped together for an index.
>
> In Hive [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-7250): for example the number of columns > 1K created memory pressure in ORC resulting in OOM. In test 15K columns were loaded and saw OOM only at 20K columns.

And [this answer](https://community.hortonworks.com/answers/6394/view.html):

> The scalability of metastore(jetty) + database chosen will also impact the performance of queries and may restrict success rate at every query execution , with increase in number of columns per table

Comment: In Hive3 and Impala was able to add a table with 8400 columns and able to run select * from HUE.